# How can I make an object stored in localstorage be null when an event happens but return to it's original form after the inverse event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, local-storage

Data has this format:

```
{
"id": 1,
"current_tenant_id": 8,
"main_tenant_id": 6,
    "employee": {
        "id": 1021,
        ...}
}
```

I have this other code:

```
const handleChange = () => (event) => {
    const localUser = getItemFromLocalStorage(LOCAL_STORAGE_NAMES.user);
    if (!isMainTenantEqualToCurrentTenant(localUser)) {
        localUser.employee = null
    }
    setInLocalStorageAsync(LOCAL_STORAGE_NAMES.user, localUser);
...
```

This works fine: after changing the tenant, it sets employee to null in localstorage. However, what I actually want, is to set `user.employee` to null when main tenant is not equal to the current tenant, but also to re-set the initial `user.employee` when the change causes the current and main tenant to be equal again, ideally without making another call to the backend (handling everything in the frontend). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not add a boolean to your employee object which will indicate whether it is null or not, instead of removing it from `localStorage`, you can just toggle the boolean

Comment: I'm confused what your exact goal is from the last paragraph, but is there anything stopping you from keeping the initial local storage in another local storage key, then resetting it upon the inverse event?